# Using Perl, how can obtain information about the icons in Windows' taskbar notification area?

Tags: windows, perl, system-tray

I am trying to write a script in Perl to read all the icons in the system tray, grab their co-ordinates & find out who owns them. I am pretty much trying to translate [this code here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3694/CTrayIconPosition-where-is-my-tray-icon).

Here is my code so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::API;
use Win32::OLE qw(in);
use Data::Dumper;

use constant wbemFlagReturnImmediately => 0x10;
use constant wbemFlagForwardOnly       => 0x20;

use constant SYNCHRONIZE => 0x00100000;
use constant STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED => 0x000F0000;
use constant PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS => (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFF);

my $TB_BUTTONCOUNT     = 0x0418;
my $TB_GETBUTTONTEXT   = 0x041B;
my $TB_GETBUTTONINFO   = 0x0441;
my $TB_GETITEMRECT     = 0x041D;
my $TB_GETBUTTON       = 0x0417;

sub get_windows_details {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $ret;

    my $objWMIService =
      Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\localhost\\root\\CIMV2")
      or die "WMI connection failed.\n";
    my $colItems =
      $objWMIService->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem",
                               "WQL",
                               wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);

    my $objItem;
    foreach $objItem (in $colItems) {
        $ret->{'osname'} = $objItem->{Caption};
    }

    $colItems =
      $objWMIService->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor",
                               "WQL",
                               wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);

    foreach $objItem (in $colItems) {
        $ret->{'osbit'} = $objItem->{AddressWidth};
    }

    return $ret;
}

sub get_autoit_tray_handle {
    my $autoit = Win32::OLE->new("AutoItX3.Control")
        or return 0;
    my $tray_hwnd = $autoit->ControlGetHandle("[Class:Shell_TrayWnd]", "", "[Class:ToolbarWindow32;Instance:1]");
    return hex $tray_hwnd;
}

sub get_tray_icon_count {
    #my $hWnd = get_tray_handle(); 
    my $hWnd = get_autoit_tray_handle(); 
    my $send_message = Win32::API->new("user32", "SendMessage", "NNII", "I");
    return $send_message->Call($hWnd, $TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);
}



# Randomly chosen icon index.
my $iIndex = 6;

my $os = get_windows_details();
if ($os->{'osbit'} == 64) {
    Win32::API::Struct->typedef('TBBUTTON', qw { int       iBitmap;
                                                 int       idCommand;
                                                 BYTE      fsState;
                                                 BYTE      fsStyle;
                                                 BYTE      bReserved[6];
                                                 DWORD_PTR dwData;
                                                 INT_PTR   iString;
                                               }
                                ) or die "Typedef error $!\n";
} else {
    Win32::API::Struct->typedef('TBBUTTON', qw { int       iBitmap;
                                                 int       idCommand;
                                                 BYTE      fsState;
                                                 BYTE      fsStyle;
                                                 BYTE      bReserved[2];
                                                 DWORD_PTR dwData;
                                                 INT_PTR   iString;
                                               }
                                ) or die "Typedef error $!\n";
}

# Get tray handle & it's proc id
my $tb_button = Win32::API::Struct->new('TBBUTTON');
my $tray_hwnd = get_autoit_tray_handle();
print "tray hwnd: $tray_hwnd\n";
my $window_thread_proc_id = Win32::API->new('user32', "GetWindowThreadProcessId", 'LP', 'N');
my $lpdwPID = pack 'L', 0;
my $pid = $window_thread_proc_id->Call($tray_hwnd, $lpdwPID);
my $dwPID = unpack 'L', $lpdwPID;
print "proc id: $dwPID\n";

# read the tray process memory to get the tray button info
my $open_process = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'OpenProcess', 'NIN', 'N') || die $!;
my $proc_hwnd = $open_process->Call(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, $dwPID);
print "proc hwnd: $proc_hwnd\n";

my $virtual_alloc = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'VirtualAllocEx', 'NNLNN', 'N');
my $lp_data = $virtual_alloc->Call($proc_hwnd, 0, $tb_button->sizeof(), 0x1000, 0x04);
print "Error allocating memory: $!\n" if $!;
print "Allocated addresss: $lp_data\n";

my $send_message = Win32::API->new('user32', 'SendMessage', 'NNIN','I');
my $get_button_status = $send_message->Call($tray_hwnd, $TB_GETBUTTON, $iIndex, $lp_data);
print "TB_GETBUTTON Status: $get_button_status\n";

my $read_process = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'NNSNP','I');
my $bytes_read = pack 'L', 0;
$read_process->Call($proc_hwnd, $lp_data, $tb_button, $tb_button->sizeof(), $bytes_read);
print "dwData: $tb_button->{'dwData'} \n";
```

I am using autoit COM DLL to get the system tray handle. Once I have the have the tray handle, I try to get it's process id & then read the process memory to get the [TBBUTTON structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is defined as follows:

```
if ($os->{'osbit'} == 64) {
    Win32::API::Struct->typedef('TBBUTTON', qw { int       iBitmap;
                                                 int       idCommand;
                                                 BYTE      fsState;
                                                 BYTE      fsStyle;
                                                 BYTE      bReserved[6];
                                                 DWORD_PTR dwData;
                                                 INT_PTR   iString;
                                               }
                                ) or die "Typedef error $!\n";
} else {
    Win32::API::Struct->typedef('TBBUTTON', qw { int       iBitmap;
                                                 int       idCommand;
                                                 BYTE      fsState;
                                                 BYTE      fsStyle;
                                                 BYTE      bReserved[2];
                                                 DWORD_PTR dwData;
                                                 INT_PTR   iString;
                                               }
                                ) or die "Typedef error $!\n";
}
```

When you execute the above code, at least on my system, here is the output I see:

```
tray hwnd: 401922
proc id: 11040
proc hwnd: 704
Allocated addresss: 32702464
TB_GETBUTTON Status: 1
dwData: 10293610267052867588
```

As you can see - the "dwData" seems to be wrong. Looks like I'm doing something wrong here:

```
my $read_process = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'ReadProcessMemory', 'NNSNP','I');
my $bytes_read = pack 'L', 0;
$read_process->Call($proc_hwnd, $lp_data, $tb_button, $tb_button->sizeof(), $bytes_read);
print "dwData: $tb_button->{'dwData'} \n";
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong there? Thanks.

Comment: I am not on a Windows system right now, but does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1013870/100754) help at all?

Comment: I think I could use Win32::Process::Memory but that means I'll have to ditch the TBBUTTON structure using Win32::API::Struct & pack the whole structure myself. I'll definitely explore that option but regardless, I want to find out what is happening, in my code, when I'm trying to copy the buffer from tray process in to my process. That is the step that last block of code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Will look at this tomorrow if noone has an answer. Poke me if I don't. Going to bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try to minimize the amount of uncertainty introduced by the various things you are pulling in, and just use the functionality provided by [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest). I also cheated with regard to bitness and structs so as to get something running on my 32-bit WinXP SP3 laptop. Here's something that runs and produces some output.

I am not sure if this is the right output, but it should at least point you in a simpler direction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature 'say';
use strict; use warnings;

use Const::Fast;
use Devel::CheckOS;
use Win32::GuiTest qw(
    AllocateVirtualBuffer
    FreeVirtualBuffer
    ReadFromVirtualBuffer
    FindWindowLike
    SendMessage
);

use YAML;

const my %TB => (
    BUTTONCOUNT => 0x0418,
    GETBUTTONTEXT => 0x041B,
    GETBUTTONINFO => 0x0441,
    GETITEMRECT => 0x041D,
    GETBUTTON => 0x0417,
);

const my %TBUTTON => (
    32 => 'iiCCCCLL',
    64 => 'iiCCCCCCCCLL',
);

my ($tray_handle) = FindWindowLike(undef, undef, 'TrayNotifyWnd');

my ($toolbar_handle) = FindWindowLike($tray_handle, undef, 'ToolbarWindow');

say for ($tray_handle, $toolbar_handle);

my $button_count = SendMessage($toolbar_handle, $TB{BUTTONCOUNT}, 0, 0);

unless (defined($button_count) and $button_count > 0) {
    die "Can't find buttons\n"
}

my $buf = AllocateVirtualBuffer($toolbar_handle, 0x20);

print Dump $buf;

my $index = int(rand $button_count);

say "Trying button = $index\n";

my $status = SendMessage(
    $toolbar_handle,
    $TB{GETBUTTON},
    $index,
    $buf->{ptr}
);

say "TB_GETBUTTON status = $status";

my $result = ReadFromVirtualBuffer($buf, 0x20);

FreeVirtualBuffer($buf);

print Dump [ map sprintf('%X', $_), unpack $TBUTTON{32}, $result ];
```

Also, not that you shoud define things like [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aAPI) functions and structs in one place and only once.

Sample output:

```
655544
393294
---
process: 1920
ptr: 28835840
Trying button = 19

TB_GETBUTTON status = 1
---
- 7
- 9
- C
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1DA23C8
- 2B70590
```

Comment: This worked. I had no idea that Win32::GuiTest provided wrappers for most of these stuff. Thank you!